# Is there a database like storage for Mac OS X Apps

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I'm hopping over to OS X App development as just a hobby. I come from a years' experience of building web apps, and I'm just so used to having a DB storage system. I've also never built mobile/desktop apps before. So, how do I get a database-like storage system for apps?

PS: I'm trying out a to-do list application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) framework is probably what you're looking for. It provides a "relational mapper" to SQLite for Mac OS and iOS applications, very similar to the functionality provided by many ORMs for web applications.

Answer (score 1):

If you have time and energy then  [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) is a way to go. On the other hand there is a library called libsqlite3.dylib which brings you familiar SQL syntax:

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into peopleInfo values(null, '%@', '%@', %d)", self.txtFirstname.text, self.txtLastname.text, [self.txtAge.text intValue]];
```

You can follow this [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/).

Comment: This is great! Makes me even more lazy, but awesome.